# Using Javascript to read Livestreamer data

Tags: javascript, live-streaming

There is a command line tool called Livestreamer that can pipe livestream data from a given url. Then it opens VLC and the actual stream is shown through VLC, I wanted to make my own app with Electron, and I was curious how I could take the data livestreamer gets, and play it on an HTML5 video player or some other kind of player. I was also curious how VLC receives the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure, that Livestreamer just passing rtmp link to VLC. RTMP is a special protocol for real time video. And you have a two ways for showing video in your app:

- Live streamer has `-o` option, like: `livestreamer someStreamUrl -o stream.mp4` - http://livestreamer.tanuki.se/cli.html#cmdoption-o, you can store stream in a file and read it by your app. Or for the same you can use option `--rtmpdump FILENAME` but you'll need RTMPDump installed on your device.
- `--player-external-http` option - http://livestreamer.tanuki.se/cli.html#cmdoption--player-external-http, as i can see can create little http server and give you special url, which you can use to hadle and play in any player which you want (in your App too). Also `--player-external-http-port SOMEPORT` to configure port and `--player-passthrough SOMEPROTOCOL` to configure protocol will be userfull.

Comment: but one question, when you use the second method, you get a local url, how do I play it, when I have a url like: http://127.0.0.1:5130/

Comment: But also it should give you external url o_O How do you want to use your app and livestreamer? You want to run livestreamer on the server, and view stream in Electron app on some other machine?

Comment: I want livestreamer to deliver the content to the electron app. Think of it like a livestream/twitch client. Similar to what VLC does when getting source from network. It is all done client side. How would i do this? I could us HLS, HTTP and RTMP. I want to stick to HLS preferably, but if there is an easier way using another protocol.

Comment: I don't know any easiest ways to do that =(( for HLS or RTMP stream, you can use for example video.js

Comment: I am using the http server. With the local and 192 address. When I chnage the passthrough to HLS with the setting i no longer get a url, it just opens in VLC. I dont know how to get the content. When i go to the given url, I just download a file which is a peice of the stream. HOW do i stream :( ?